# Angular2, how to clear URL query params on router navigate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am struggling with clearing out URL params during nav in Angular 2.4.2. I have tried attaching every option to clear the params in the below navigation line, or any mix therein with navigate, or navigateByUrl, but cannot figure out how to accomplish.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.url, { queryParams: {}, preserveQueryParams: false });
```

As an example I am at route `/section1/page1?key1=abc&key2=def` and want to stay at the same route but remove all the url parameters, so the end result should be `/section/page1`

Comment: Maybe - `this.location.replaceState(path_only_str)` after router event. -
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html -
What is the referrer? cuz you can also use `skipLocationChange` on routerLink to remain in the current state.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As DeborahK pointed out, when I was navigating to this.router.url, that URL already had the url params embedded. To solve I stripped the params off the URL as a string, and then used navigateByUrl to jump there.

```
let url: string = this.router.url.substring(0, this.router.url.indexOf("?"));
this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 15):

Using `navigateByUrl` will drop off the query parameters if you pass it a URL without the query parameters.

Or you could try:

```
this.router.navigate(this.router.url, { queryParams: {}});
```

NOTE: `navigate` and not `navigateByUrl`

Does that work?

Comment: That's what I had thought too, and what the docs seem to indicate should the case, but it's definitely not. In the case mentioned above I use `navigateByUrl(this.router.url)` while the url is something like "domain.com/section/page?param=a&other=b" ... I'd expect it to have to "domain.com/section/page" but the url parameters persist

Comment: You are passing the URL *with* the query parameters so it will continue to have those parameters. You'd need to pass the url *without* the parameters.

Comment: There are some additional suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186636/remove-a-parameter-from-queryparams-angular-2

Comment: I'm adding one more suggestion to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks DeborahK you were totally on the right track; however, that additional suggestion also didn't work, the url parameters would persist since this.router.url has them embedded. I have solved by simply stripping the params off the string manually and then routing by url (self-answered below)

Comment: how to make it without using queryParams? We have normal params like `/page/param1/` and we want to replace those params from component, which doesnt know about the current URL

Comment: In fact, it doesn't work. this.router.url includes the query params now

Comment: This worked for me: `this.routerExtensions.navigate([this.router.url.substring(0, this.router.url.indexOf("?"))], { animated: isIOS ? true : false, skipLocationChange: true });`

Comment: I did something similar - `this.router.navigate([this.location.path().substring(0, this.location.path().indexOf('?'))]);`

Comment: can i use the same for redirecting to external url ? for example I am in xyz.com I want to redirect abc.com . Any suggestions please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338440/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-in-angular2

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to reload the page you can also use `Location`

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
[...]
this.location.replaceState(this.location.path().split('?')[0], '');
```

`this.location.path()` provides you with the current path. You can remove the params by resetting the page's path with everything in the URL before the `?`.

Comment: Work perfect if you don't want to refresh the page

Answer (score 10):

You can add `replaceUrl: true` in your navigation extras. This way, the router will navigate to the same page but you still remain in the same state in history with the url parameters gone, while still allowing you to go back to the previous route.

From the docs:

> [Navigates while replacing the current state in history.](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

```
this.router.navigate([], { replaceUrl: true});
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the skipLocationChange option and it will not show parameters: 
suppose your url is

> http://localhost/view

now something in your code 
sets the query parameters to

> ?q=all&viewtype=total

without the skipLocationChange your url in the browser ( after calling navigate) would be :

> http://localhost/view?q=all&viewtype=total

with skipLocationChange : true it remains

> http://localhost/view

```
let qp = { q : "all" , viewtype : "total" } 
this.router.navigate(['/view'], {  queryParams: qp,skipLocationChange: true });
```

Comment: As I came late here with the same problem, in my opinion this is the right solution to use

Comment: can i use the same for redirecting to external url ? for example I am in xyz.com I want to redirect abc.com . Any suggestions please

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple one

```
this.router.navigate([], {});
```

// Or

```
this.router.navigate([], {
  queryParams: {
   param1:'',
   param2:''
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

This will clear the URL with no hardcode and will not re-load the page.

```
constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router
    )
...
     this.router.navigate([], {
                relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
                queryParams: {},
                replaceUrl: true,
            });
```

Comment: Worked, nice one! :)

Answer (score 3):

From angular 7.2 onward, you can use state

Sending

```
this.router.navigate(['routename'], { state: { param1: 'bar' } });
```

Receiving

```
let paramobj = history.state;
console.log(paramobj.param1);
```

By this you can send even large complex objects from template as well.

Comment: Could you provide links to the Angular documentation for information on the API's that you use?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: And this `history` object?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper it is ann inner object of Window object . For more details visit - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Answer (score 0):

I have updated [@Joshua Ohana answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43683497/5376073) a little bit:

```
    const getRouterPathUrl = (fullUrl: string): string => (fullUrl.includes("?") ? fullUrl.substring(0, fullUrl.indexOf("?")) : fullUrl);

    this.router.navigate([getRouterPathUrl(this.router.url)],
        {
            queryParams: params,
            replaceUrl: true
        }
    );
```

This way, you will be able to update and clear query params on any change from your app.