# Clear queryparams from URL after params taken in variables

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to get queryparams from URL in `service`.
I am taking params using this

URL: `http://localhost:4200/?param1=15&param2=abcdef`

```
this._activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.p1 = params['param1'];
        this.p2 = params['param2'];
});
```

so, now I got params in `this.p1` and `this.p2` I want to clear the queryparams from URL like,
`http://localhost:4200/`

Please suggest me a way here

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate back to the same with empty params like
refer this [Route params clearing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43666001/7785198)

Comment: `this._router.navigate(this._router.url, { queryParams: {}});` I'm getting `argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.)`