# Angular remove query param when call back button

Tags: angular, typescript, url, angular-routing

I need to check if my income URL is a specific formate then open modal and do something. I do this with this code:

```
route.queryParams.subscribe(async params => {
      if (!isNaN(params.rt)) {
        console.log("URL Match");
        this.show = true;
      } else {
        console.log("URL does not Match");
      }
    });
```

my format should be like :

```
www.example.com?=123456
```

but i need if complete modal Process, **remove** query param from url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove query params you can do like below.

```
let url: string = this.router.url.substring(0, this.router.url.indexOf("?"));
this.router.navigateByUrl(url); // where this.router will be intialized in ex:// constructor(private router:Router) {}
```

This link might help.

[cleary query params in router (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665206/angular2-how-to-clear-url-query-params-on-router-navigate)