# how do I trim or remove the header URL containing data in it using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, browser

so in one component I'm having a form and after filling the form details, when the send button is clicked I send the data in encrypted format to another component using header. Belowis the code:

```
send(){
     this.router.navigate(['/customerportal/insta-pay/insurance-plan'],{
        queryParams:{data:btoa(JSON.stringify(data))}
      })
}
```

and when I look at the header of the component, I find this:

```
http://localhost:4200/customerportal/insta-pay/insurance-plan?data=W3siY29udGFjdCI6eyJtb2JpbGVOdW1iZXIiOiI5OTg5ODM1ODk1IiwiZW1haWwiOiJ2aXNoYWwxMjNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiZmRudnZu
```

And, what I want is that I want to trim the header URL after **data=W3siY29udGFjdCI6eyJtb2JpbGVOdW1iZXIiOiI5OT**

and also that this **data should be deleted completely as it is showing/visible in the sources tab** of the browser and when I click on it the data is visible and that page is still accessible with all the sensitive data information.

Comment: If you don't want to pass the `data` parameter anymore, just remove it from the `queryParams` object altogether.

Comment: I do want to pass the data, but after using that I want to remove data from parameter, is there any way of doing that?

Comment: I think it should be possible if you navigate again to the same route, without specifying the query params. Have a look at [a similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665206/angular2-how-to-clear-url-query-params-on-router-navigate) for inspiration on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, using query params doesn't seem to be the correct way to pass your `data` param.
Check *[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864303/send-data-through-routing-paths-in-angular)* to have a complete answer on how we can pass params through Angular routing, and choose the most suited solution to your case ;)